# Writing a Dictionary with a list of values to an Excel file

Tags: python, excel, xlsxwriter

using python3
i have a dictionary with over 100 keys. each key's value is a list. what i want to do is write the each key of the dictionary to an Excel document with each term having its own cell, all on the same row.

```
row = 0
col = 0

myDictionary = {
    'car seat':['$10', '12', 'IT1'],
    'piano':['$12', '2', 'IT1'],
    'picture frame':['$2', '14', 'IT1'],
    'shoes':['$20', '13', 'IT1'],
    }

for key in myDictionary.keys()::
    Result = [str(key), myDictionary[key]]
    worksheet.write_row(row, col, Result)
    row += 1
```

ExpectedOutput.xlsx (header not included):

```
KEY           / listvalue1 / listvalue2 / listvalue3
car seat      / $10        / 12         / IT1
piano         / $12        / 2          / IT1
picture frame / $2         / 14         / IT1
shoes         / $20        / 13         / IT1
```

the problem im having is that i can only get Excel to use two columns: 
key / value

instead of the 4 columns that i need:
key / value1 / value2 / value3

since i have over 100 entries in my dictionary, the goal is to write each key to Excel so i can sort it easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do is print a comma separated list to a CSV file.

```
"KEY","listvalue1","listvalue2","listvalue3"
"car seat","$10", "12", "IT1"
"piano","$12", "2", "IT1"
"picture frame","$2", "14", "IT1"
"shoes","$20", "13", "IT1"
```

This can easily be done in Python and Excel should be able to open it. You can then manipulate the data in a spreadsheet or you can then copy it into another spreadsheet, or spreadsheet tab, if you need it elsewhere.

Comment: that worked perfectly. i suppose i was overthinking it by trying to use a dictionary instead of a list, because i wanted the terms to be 'latched' to each other. but by using a list, and writing it to the xlsx file with worksheet.write_row() for every iteration, i got it to do exactly what i needed. thanks!!

Answer (score 7):

Rather than embed the key into the list (which isn't done correctly in this case) you can just write the `key` and `value` explicitly:

```
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('example.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

myDictionary = {
    'car seat':['$10', '12', 'IT1'],
    'piano':['$12', '2', 'IT1'],
    'picture frame':['$2', '14', 'IT1'],
    'shoes':['$20', '13', 'IT1'],
    }

row = 0
for key in myDictionary.keys():
    worksheet.write(row, 0, key)
    worksheet.write_row(row, 1, myDictionary[key])
    row += 1

workbook.close()
```

Output:

[image]

Note, you may want to iterate through your data and convert it more explicitly, for example, convert the dollar values to numbers.